# Multiple rtsp ip camera stream on raspberry using python opencv lagging and increasing delay

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to analyse image from IP cameras (from 2 to 6 cameras) with a Raspberry 3b+.

I'm using python opencv but there is a increasing delay (as the video was in x0.5 so the delay accumulates)

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time

class ThreadedCamera(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 2)
       
        # FPS = 1/X
        # X = desired FPS
        self.FPS = 1/30
        self.FPS_MS = int(self.FPS * 1000)
        
        # Start frame retrieval thread
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        
    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            time.sleep(self.FPS)
            
    def show_frame(self):
        cv2.imshow('frame', self.frame)
        cv2.waitKey(self.FPS_MS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = 'rtsp://user:psword@192.168.8.108:554/Streaming/Channels/1401'
    threaded_camera = ThreadedCamera(src)
    while True:
        try:
            threaded_camera.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

I try without the FPS logic and the result is the same (I try to reduce FPS and it doesnt work). I don't need 30 FPS but I want minimum 3 FPS.

What can I do ? Is there an good alternative to opencv ? Do I have to use another language

Comment: the source camera determines the stream's frame rate. you must adjust that there, or drop frames on the receiving end. you **cannot throttle** the stream on the receiving end. sleeping is also wrong.

Comment: As I said, even without all the FPS logic (and thus without sleeping) the result is the same.

Comment: "drop frames on the receiving end" then. either use a fixed divisor (emit every n-th frame only from the thread) or implement some more complex logic to drop frames.

Comment: If you are referring to CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT and CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES I have tried and unfortunately the capture takes more than 1.5 seconds.

Comment: I did not refer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `time.sleep` after `cv2.capture`.

I don't know why but it works for me.